# Error in Shipment Email in magento 2 when creating programmatically

Tags: programmatically, shipment, magento2.4.3.p1, shipment-email

I created the shipment programmatically. Shipment is created and email is not sending. I am getting the following error. I followed RAKESH JESADIYA's [this tutorial](https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/how-to-programmatically-create-shipment-in-magento-2/) for this task.

> main.CRITICAL: Error: Call to a member function getParentItem() on null in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myproject/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/shipment/items.phtml:23

My code is below.

```
public function createShipment($orderId){
    try {
        $order = $this->orderRepository->get($orderId);
        if (!$order->getId()) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__('The order no longer exists.'));
        }
        
        if ( $order->canShip() )
        {   
            $shipment = $this->orderConverter->toShipment($order);
            foreach ($order->getAllItems() AS $orderItem) {
                if (! $orderItem->getQtyToShip() || $orderItem->getIsVirtual()) {
                    continue;
                }
                $qtyShipped = $orderItem->getQtyToShip();
                $shipmentItem = $this->orderConverter->itemToShipmentItem($orderItem)->setQty($qtyShipped);
                $shipment->addItem($shipmentItem);
            }
            
            $shipment->register();
            $shipment->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);

            try {
                $transaction = $this->transactionFactory->create()->addObject($shipment)
                    ->addObject($shipment->getOrder())
                    ->save();
                $shipmentId = $shipment->getIncrementId();
                $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Shipment Generated SuccessFully'));
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
               $this->messageManager->addError(__('We can\'t generate shipment.'));
            }
            if ($shipment) {
                try {
                    $this->shipmentSender->send($shipment);
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    $this->messageManager->addError(__('We can\'t send the shipment right now.'));
                }
            }
            
        }

        
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Kindly notice i have used every dependencies called in this function in the main class.

**But for the same created shipment i can send the email from admin.** What is this error and may i know any fix for this.

Comment: #mujahidh any solution on this??

Comment: Also looking to retrieve products in shipment email but $_item->getProduct() always returns null. Did you figure this out?